# Import Mainframe files in Sqoop - Packed decimal Conversion

Tags: hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to pull few mainframe datasets into HDFS. There is an option in sqoop that supports mainframe connectivity. The problem I have is that few mainframe files contain packed decimal(comp-3) and binary(comp) Fields.

My questions are:

1. Sqoop does a job of converting EBCDIC to ASCII using the mainframe plugin. However, does it support conversion of packed decimal fields by default ?
2. If not, how do i get this done and load into HDFS ? Any open source utilities to get this done. Suggestions would help.
3. Is it possible to pass the metadata(copybook) of the mainframe file through sqoop command ?

Appreciate your help!!

Thanks,
Vinoth

Comment: Hi Vinoth,
By any chance did you found answers to your questions I have similar problem in importing Mainframe data

Comment: @chhayavishwakarma - Due to connectivity issues at my end, i wasn't able to test SQOOP import using the mainframe plugin - I doubt it can convert packed decimal as somewhere i read that the mainframe datasets need to be character converted before import. May be you try cobol2j(open source..) and check if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. No
2. I haven't tested it, but looks promising http://rbheemana.github.io/Cobol-to-Hive/
3. In order to do that, the copybook has to be visible via mainframe's ftp

Comment: I have tested it and it's working fine but the only problem I am facing while FTP the big files to local unix and thereafter movng it to hdfs to use the above jar. what could be the efficient way to get the files directly on hdfs, without need to ftp them to local unix. any suggestion?